# Irregular blanks between inline list elements

Tags: html, css, list

There is some irregular blanks in [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/s8d77r2z/). It had to be line-by-line and pictures had to be immediatly after each one. I wonder that why it is happen and how i can fix it.                               .

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="videos">
        <div id="videos-title-box">
            <div id="videos-title-text"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="videos-wrapper">
        <ul id="videos-ul">
            <li class="single-video-li">
                <div class="single-video-block">
                    <a class="img" href="#">
                        <img class="video-thumb" src="http://tr.nociicon.com/public/upload/fdthum/2014/10/10/face_smile.png">
                    </a>            
                </div>
            </li>
.
.
.
            <li class="single-video-li">
                <div class="single-video-block">
                    <img class="video-thumb" src="http://tr.nociicon.com/public/upload/fdthum/2014/10/10/face_smile.png">

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
    width: 90%;
  margin: auto;

}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#videos{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;

}
#videos-wrapper{
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #101010;
    border-color: #222;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    position: relative;
}
#videos-ul{
        left: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul li.single-video-li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
.single-video-block{
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;

}
.video-thumb{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

RESULT:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#videos-ul {
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    position: relative;
    font-size:0; /* <======   to get rid of white spaces when inline-block element are present as child */
}
```

Make you repeating `li` similar like below

```
<li class="single-video-li">
    <div class="single-video-block">
        <a class="img" href="#">
            <img class="video-thumb"src="http://tr.nociicon.com/public/upload/fdthum/2014/10/10/face_smile.png" />
        </a>    
    </div>
</li>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s8d77r2z/3/)

Comment: which parts i am repeating? I really can't find out. I can not see any difference between your fiddle and my fiddle. But your's is working fine.

Comment: You are not repeating similar blocks, like others pointed all your repeating li should be similar in structure.

Answer (score 2):

You had multiple `<div class="single-video-block">`s within some `<li>`s
http://jsfiddle.net/s8d77r2z/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are including two divs in the `li` element. Please see this updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8d77r2z/2/)